# How to convert UNICODE characters within a string, to their string representation?

Tags: javascript, string, ascii

Basically I have these strings

```
var String1 = 'Concepciu00f3n';
var String2 = 'u00d1eembucu00fa';
```

I want to convert them back so that they will look like this:

```
var String1 = 'Concepción';
var String2 = 'Ñeembucú';
```

I've been searching a lot but I haven't found a solution in js yet

Edit: This is how the data is stored in my DB

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'inc/datos-graficos-data',         
            dataType : "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                q: 'guardar_grafico',
                id: id,
                headers: headers,
                datos: save_data,
                meta: editor,
                tipo: tipo_grafico,
                array: selectedRows,//This is the array with all the strings that gets saved with unicodes
                excel: excel_format
            },
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                //$("#ventasGrafico").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'>");
            },
            success: function(json) {
                $('#modal_parseo').modal('hide');
                //SWAL
                Swal.fire(
                'Exito!',
                json,
                'success'
                ).then((result) => {
                    // Reload the Page
                    location.reload();
                });
            },
            cache: true
        });
```

This is what my selectedRows array looks like before I send it via ajax, note that some of the values on the "agrupacion" keys are strings with special characters like "Asunción" or "Ñeembucú".

```
const selectedRows = [
  {agrupacion: 'Asunción', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 105.1, col2016: 108, col2017: 112.2, col2018: 106.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 103, col2016: 106.7, col2017: 115, col2018: 106.8},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 107.2, col2016: 109.3, col2017: 109.4, col2018: 107.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Concepción', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 77.8, col2016: 79.4, col2017: 82.9, col2018: 74.3},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 76.4, col2016: 80.2, col2017: 81.3, col2018: 71.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 79.3, col2016: 78.5, col2017: 84.6, col2018: 77.2},
  {agrupacion: 'San Pedro', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 76.8, col2016: 77.7, col2017: 77.2, col2018: 70.2},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 77.2, col2016: 79.1, col2017: 79.8, col2018: 69.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 76.3, col2016: 76.3, col2017: 74.5, col2018: 70.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Cordillera', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 77.9, col2016: 77.5, col2017: 75.6, col2018: 67.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 76.4, col2016: 78.1, col2017: 73.7, col2018: 67.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 79.5, col2016: 76.7, col2017: 77.6, col2018: 67.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Guairá', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 67.8, col2016: 64.8, col2017: 67.3, col2018: 63.2},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 66.6, col2016: 65.9, col2017: 66.5, col2018: 63.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 69, col2016: 63.7, col2017: 68.2, col2018: 62.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Caaguazú', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 75, col2016: 74.5, col2017: 76.5, col2018: 73.2},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 75.3, col2016: 73.4, col2017: 75.4, col2018: 72.6},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 74.7, col2016: 75.7, col2017: 77.6, col2018: 73.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Caazapá', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 63.6, col2016: 56.6, col2017: 59.8, col2018: 57.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 63.9, col2016: 55.6, col2017: 59.6, col2018: 57.4},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 63.2, col2016: 57.5, col2017: 59.9, col2018: 56.8},
  {agrupacion: 'Itapúa', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 74.3, col2016: 69.6, col2017: 66.2, col2018: 63.7},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 73.6, col2016: 69.1, col2017: 67.7, col2018: 65.4},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 75.2, col2016: 70.1, col2017: 64.7, col2018: 62},
  {agrupacion: 'Misiones', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 79.4, col2016: 74.6, col2017: 79.2, col2018: 72.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 81.3, col2016: 72.7, col2017: 77.9, col2018: 72.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 77.4, col2016: 76.5, col2017: 80.5, col2018: 72.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Paraguarí', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 67.2, col2016: 66, col2017: 63.5, col2018: 62.7},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 67.7, col2016: 67.2, col2017: 65, col2018: 62.3},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 66.7, col2016: 64.8, col2017: 62, col2018: 63.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Alto Paraná', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 98.9, col2016: 92.8, col2017: 94.2, col2018: 92.3},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 97, col2016: 93.4, col2017: 94.3, col2018: 92.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 100.8, col2016: 92.2, col2017: 94.2, col2018: 92.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Central', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 87, col2016: 85.2, col2017: 90.3, col2018: 83.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 86.6, col2016: 84.5, col2017: 90.6, col2018: 83.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 87.5, col2016: 86, col2017: 90, col2018: 83.4},
  {agrupacion: 'Ñeembucú', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 68.4, col2016: 67, col2017: 70.3, col2018: 69.9},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 63.9, col2016: 69.8, col2017: 69.7, col2018: 65.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 73.1, col2016: 64.1, col2017: 70.9, col2018: 74.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Amambay', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 98, col2016: 100.4, col2017: 100.8, col2018: 95.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 99.8, col2016: 100.5, col2017: 101.9, col2018: 97.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 96.1, col2016: 100.3, col2017: 99.6, col2018: 92.5},
  {agrupacion: 'Canindeyú', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 79.5, col2016: 82.3, col2017: 85, col2018: 82.2},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 77.6, col2016: 79.9, col2017: 82.2, col2018: 82.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 81.5, col2016: 84.7, col2017: 88, col2018: 82.4},
  {agrupacion: 'Presidente Hayes', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 82, col2016: 81.8, col2017: 87.5, col2018: 78},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 82.9, col2016: 78.6, col2017: 88.5, col2018: 81.3},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 81.1, col2016: 85.2, col2017: 86.4, col2018: 74.6},
  {agrupacion: 'Boquerón', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 99.3, col2016: 103.7, col2017: 97.6, col2018: 111.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 98.2, col2016: 107.4, col2017: 100.8, col2018: 112.3},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 100.4, col2016: 99.8, col2017: 94.3, col2018: 109.8},
  {agrupacion: 'Alto Paraguay', col2015: 0, col2016: 0, col2017: 0, col2018: 0},
  {agrupacion: 'Total', col2015: 83, col2016: 75.2, col2017: 88.7, col2018: 81.6},
  {agrupacion: 'Hombre', col2015: 88, col2016: 77, col2017: 92, col2018: 90.1},
  {agrupacion: 'Mujer', col2015: 77.7, col2016: 73.4, col2017: 85.2, col2018: 72.9}];
```

datos-graficos-data.php file:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
switch ($q) {
   case 'guardar_grafico':
        $db = DataBase::conectar();
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];//ID
        $froala = $db->clearText($_REQUEST['meta']);
        $tipo_grafico = $db->clearText($_REQUEST['tipo']);
        $tipo_excel = $db->clearText($_REQUEST['excel']);
        $datos_grafico = $_REQUEST['datos'];//OBJECT ARRAY
        $cabecera_grafico = $_REQUEST['headers'];//ARRAY HEADER EX=[2015,2016,2017,ETC]
        $array = $_REQUEST['array'];//ARRAY OF SELECTED DATA
        $json_encoded_array = json_encode($array); //JSON_ENCODE TO STORE IN DB
        
        //IRRELEVANT CODE HERE

        //UPDATE DATA, THIS IS WHERE THAT ARRAY IS SAVED
        $db->setQuery("UPDATE indicadores SET 
        datos='$froala',
        tipo_excel='$tipo_excel',
        tipo_grafico='$tipo_grafico',
        datos_grafico='$json_encoded_array'
        WHERE id_indicador=$id");
        if(!$db->alter()){
            echo "Error: ". $db->getError();
            $db->rollback();  //REVERT CHANGES                
        exit;
        }

        $db->commit();

        echo json_encode('Data saved successfully');
    break;
}
```

Comment: For the general case, not possible - how would you determine whether a particular segment was intended to be part of the string literal, or an escape sequence?

Comment: Where do these strings come from?

Comment: Better to add a backslash before unicode sequence : `'Concepci\u00f3n'`

Comment: Are they really messed up in your source code like that?

Comment: yeah, those strings were returned via ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your question to the following...

"How to convert UNICODE values to UNICODE characters within a string?"

If that is the question, then I think you can build something like this…

Create an object in JavaScript containing all the key/value pairs for the entire Unicode table.  Here is that link https://unicode-table.com/en/

All Unicode characters should be preceded by “U+” then four  alpha numeric characters after the “U+”.  The following code should work for finding multiple Unicodes within a string.

You will have to manually create the entire Unicode table as a JavaScript object or as a .json and import that .json into your application.  Either way the following code will work…

```js
const objUnicode = {
    '00F3': 'ó',
    '006E': 'n',
    '00D1': 'Ñ',
    '00FA': 'ú'
}

//let string1 = 'ConcepciU+00F3n'
//convertUnicode(string1)

let string2 = 'U+00D1eembucU+00FA'

convertUnicode(string2)

function convertUnicode(string) {
    let arraySplit = string.split('U+') //split string at U+ which excludes the U+ from the split
    let arrayUnicode = [] //empty array to hold the unicode values to be used as keys
    let unicode
    //extract all unicodes within the string and add to array
    arraySplit.forEach((element) => {
        if (element === '') {
            return
        }
        unicode = element.slice(0, 4)
        arrayUnicode.push(unicode)
    })
    // loop through all the unicodes in the array and replace orignal string unicode values with string values from objUnicode
    arrayUnicode.forEach((element) => {
        string = string.replaceAll(`U+${element}`, objUnicode[element])
    })

    console.log(string)
}
```

Comment: mm in other words, before I even do all these I have to add the + sign to every unicode after the "U" that I find on every string

Comment: You cannot just add a +.  What if the "u" is part of the string you want to keep.  You need some type of delimeter to parse against.  Could be a +U.  Could be a \.  But unlike my other colleagues suggested is cannot be done, I wanted to show it that it can be doen.  Not sure why my answer was downvoted.  It actually works!!!  You need some way of being able to parse the string.  You need to konw where to spilt the string, parse out the unicode value, translate the unicode value to corresponding unicode character.  Are you receiving that unicode value from another system?

Comment: ik it works as long as the string comes with the U+unicode, which is not the case here. I know I can't just add a + After every U becuz some of them are part of the string that I want to keep but those Us they all have something in common, they are always followed by numbers. I have to make some kind of function that can find all those, insert the + and then try the function. And I didn't downvote your answer, don't blame me

Comment: then there is no way to do as @CertainPerformance suggested.  I showed you the only way to do it.  Otherwise it's impossible without AI because some of the unicode values actually are letters.  What I posted is the only way.  So, if you are inserting the unicode values then its simpe to add a D+ to the value.  Very simple.

Comment: The u is NOT always followed by numbers.  It is followed by characters and numbers.  Again, impossible unless you follow what I told you.  If you are receiving that input from another system then you could ask them to change the "u" to a "U+" to conform to the standard.

Comment: I do appreciate the fact that you took your time to answer my question, i will find a way to somehow insert that + to my string and try your function out

Comment: If you can share how the unicode value is being inserted I can probably work with you to modify it before it gets inserted into the string.  Can you share?

Comment: Also, I would see if you can change that lower case "u" to an uppercase "U" so you end up with "U+" before the Unicode value.

Comment: I will update the question to share how the data is inserted

Comment: I think I've solved the problem with a simple replace() function. 

`var a = "u00d1eembucu00fa";

var string1 = a.replace(/u00/g, "u+00");`

Check the fiddle with your function 
https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/h1squ89k/28/

Comment: solved the issue by using the replace() function on the string first and then I applied your approach and works like a charm so I upvoted your answer. That doesn't solve the issue of why the strings are saved like that but it helps with the messed up data

Comment: Awesome!  thanks for posting on fiddle.  If you could give credit to Let's App! that would be greatly appreciated.  Also, keep in mind if the length of the unicode values changes the function will need to be updated.  And, you can use any character like you you did so you "know" where in the string to slice and dice.  I only recommended U+ because that is the standard, but \u or anything you know wont show up anywhere else in the string should work!  Good luck to you my friend!

Comment: Will do, I appreciated